# How can this random fetch of data works?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

In the get_batch function, how can it ensure each random fetch of the indexs from x and y are unique? Because its random nature, does it get all the data from x and y at the end of the 'get_batch' iterations?

Instead of random fetch, shouldn't it get the data sequentially?

```
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = x**3 - 4*x**2 - 2*x + 2

def get_batch(x, y, batch_size=20):
    idxs = np.random.randint(0, len(x), (batch_size))
    return x[idxs], y[idxs]
```

Then get the batch call:

```
x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(x, y)
```

I did a simulation test:

```
In [48]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     print(np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                      
[3 0 2 0 4 2 2 1 4 3]
[1 2 1 3 0 0 0 4 2 2]
[3 0 0 3 0 2 0 2 1 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach cannot ensure that it get all the data from x and y at the end of the `get_batch` iterations. A better approach would be to shuffle the data at the start of each epoch and then generate the batches sequentially. Of course if you are doing [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) to fit different models on different samples from data (with replacement), this is a valid approach.